# Transformar un array multidimensional, en un simple array

Tags: java, array

Estoy tratando de transformar un array

```
Integer[][] mapArray = new Integer[52][52];
    for (int w = 0; w < 52; w++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 52; x++) {
            mapArray[w][x] = -1;
        }
    }
```

En un array de una única dimensión

```
Integer[] mapArray1d = new Integer[52 * 52];
```

Pero lo unico que consigo es hacerlo mal, me dejo posiciones en null. ¿ alguna idea para solucionar mi problema ?

Comment: Exactamente cual es el erroy y como estás pasando el mapArray a mapArrayId?

Comment: @Sergio1871 ya lo conseguido sacar acabo de postear una posible solución

Answer (score 1):

Una forma simple y sencilla que no se me había ocurrido puede ser la siguiente:

```
Integer[][] mapArray = new Integer[52][52];
    for (int w = 0; w < 52; w++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 52; x++) {
            mapArray[w][x] = -1;
        }
    }
Integer[] mapArray1d = new Integer[52 * 52];

    int index = 0;
    for (int w = 0; w < mapArray.length; w++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapArray[w].length; x++) {
            mapArray1d[index] = mapArray[w][x];
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int tamanio = 6, count = 0;  
    // inicializando la matriz
    Integer[][] mapArray = new Integer[tamanio][tamanio];
    for (int w = 0; w < tamanio; w++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < tamanio; x++) {
            mapArray[w][x] = -1;
        }
    }
    // creando el array
    Integer[] mapArray1d = new Integer[tamanio * tamanio];

    for (int w = 0; w < tamanio; w++) {
        System.arraycopy(mapArray[w], 0, mapArray1d, count, tamanio);
        count += tamanio;
    }
    // mostrando el resultado
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mapArray1d));
```

Una breve descripción del método

**System.arrayCopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)**

src -- El array con la data origen.

srcPos -- La posición inicial del array origen.

dest -- El array destino.

destPos -- La posición desde donde se iniciara a escribir en el array destino.

length -- El número de elementos a ser copiados.

Comment: Hola @w33haa, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. En lo posible edita la respuesta de tal manera que expliques correctamente el código que anexas.

Answer (score 1):

public static void main (String [] agrs)
    {
        Integer[][] mapArray = new Integer[52][52];
        for (int w = 0; w < 52; w++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 52; x++) {
                mapArray[w][x] = -1;
            }
        }

```
    //se crea arreglo Auxiliar el cual tendra un largo de igual al largo por el alto de la matriz
    Integer []arrayAuxiliar = new Integer[mapArray.length * mapArray.length];
    int indice = 0;
    //se recorre cada subArreglo del arreglo original
    for(Integer[] arregloNumerosEnteros : mapArray )
    {
        //se recorre cada Integer del subArreglo y se añade al arreglo Auxiliar
        for(Integer numeroEntero : arregloNumerosEnteros)
        {
            arrayAuxiliar[indice] = numeroEntero;
            indice++;
        }
    }

    //se recorre el arreglo auxiliar y se imprime su contenido
    for(Integer entero : arrayAuxiliar)
        System.out.print(arrayAuxiliar.length);

}
```